# Macroexpand is not expanding

Tags: clojure

So I am trying to write a macro to test if a number is positive, negative, or zero and after testing will do a specific action for each of the three possibilities. My code is...

```
(defmacro numif [e p z n] `(if (pos? ~e) ~p (if (zero? ~e) ~z (if (neg? ~e) ~n))))
```

When I try to expand it I receive the answer and not the expanded version of the answer,like so...

```
user=> (macroexpand (numif 2 "pos" "zero" "neg"))
"pos"
```

I understand that it might have to do with my ~ placement but I can't seem to figure out where and why. If someone could explain to me why I am not getting a full expansion of my statement that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget quote `'` ;p

```
(macroexpand '(numif 2 "pos" "zero" "neg"))
;; -> (if (clojure.core/pos? 2) "pos" (if (clojure.core/zero? 2) "zero" (if (clojure.core/neg? 2) "neg")))
```